# Windows Home Server 2011 doesn't install in virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-home-server

Info:
I have virtualbox, the iso file of Windows Home Server 2011 and I created a virtual hard disk with 20gb of storage (maybe not enough space?).

### The hard disk is in the sata controller and the iso is the primary ide.

When I start virtualbox after windows is loading I get to the setup, then I click Install it finds my 20gb hard disk.
Then I click confirm that everything will be deleted so then I click install.

But the problem happens here, It says error and restart the installation. Everytime I restart I reach here to the same problem.

The log says:
I don't know how to copy the error log from virtualbox to my primary windows.
It says the partition size is too large to support data partition (Don't understand it)
Then it says the value for this setting is invalid 
At the end it says Exited 0x80004005

Can someone tell me how to install windows home server in virtualbox and fix this problem.

Comment: Windows Home Server only needs 10gb (9.25)!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 20 GB you have allocated to the hard disk in your virtual machine is inadequate. According to the system requirements below, you will need to allocate at least 160 GB to get it to install.

The system requirements for Microsoft Home Server 2011 are listed as (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Home_Server_2011#System_requirements)):

> CPU  -  1.3 GHz dual core or 1.4 GHz single core; x86-64 architecture
>   RAM  -  2 GB (8 GB Maximum)
>   **Hard disk space  -  At least one 160 GB drive**

Comment: Will it work with 100gb?

Comment: Not sure. There's not a lot of documentation on it out there. One person in the reviews section on [newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416443) mentions it's possible on 40 GB, but hard to say if that's true. I'm just going by Microsoft's specifications. It's worth a shot at 100 GB though.

Comment: When I opened save as from the log to go to the file and right clicked the setup.exe and chose run as an administrator it started installing. Currently it is 75% done expanding windows files (still with the 20gb disk)

Comment: It is now preparing my server

Comment: What did you go with, 100 GB?

Comment: No! With only 20gb!! Don't know how but so far its working! It says wait 30 minutes.

Comment: Hmm might have to delete this answer then if it succeeds. Let me know if it makes it to the end.

Comment: I think it completed the installation,  there is windows home server 2011 at the bottom of the screen where windows 7 would be. The first thing that happened is 5 minutes of "shutting down" screen.

Comment: It WORKS!!!!!!! The desktop just came!

Comment: How much disk space did it end up taking up?

Comment: I just installed windows home server 2011 without a 160gb hard disk!!! Windows Home Server only need 10gb!!!!!! (9.25)!

Answer (score -1):

Need Help With Windows is currently out he will reply you (n8te) later.

Windows Home Servet can be installed on (almost) anything that supports 64 bits windows 7 and since 20gb is enough for windows (windows 7 only needs 10-15gb) Window Home Server will also work with 20gb.

The 160gb is not required but if you're planning to backup multiple computers overnight for example thats when the 160gb is recommend. (You don't even need 160gb for backup).